# restricting the X-axis labels to only labels provided

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a range of weekly dates that span many years. I am supposed to set up a graph (bar, column, line, etc.), with the dates as the x-axis range. How could I format the chart such that it only displays the dates given? At the moment, the chart displays every week, which takes up a lot of space and is not useful because the associated Y-value is just a zero.
For example, if I have the weeks:

```
6/17/16 7/1/16 8/26/16 9/30/16
```

How could I get only these to display on the X, rather than every week?

In other words, I want the X-axis grid lines to only reflect the given x-values.

Comment: Can the dates be equally spaced, or do you need the distance between them to reflect the *time* between the dates?
Also, you should show what you have so far to help people understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The dates are equally spaced. I don't really have anything to show, but I've tried to make some cells NA, however this still displays large gaps between dates. The dates are along the x-axis. @Bandersnatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this for a column chart:

[image]

After creating the chart, click on it to select it and choose "Data Series..." from the Chart menu.  In that dialog box, replace the default values for "Category (X) axis labels" with the dates you want, in double quotes, and separated by commas.

[image]

Note that Excel adds the curly brackets, and I kept getting an error message if I tried to add a value inside the brackets. Taking them out made the edit go OK.  I'm using Excel 2011 for Mac, so this may not be a universal feature/bug.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.
This was a good suggestion, however I forgot to state that the dates are a result of formulas, so I cannot manually enter "" around the dates.
I have a new directive from my mentor though, and that is to include all weeks, which is easy by changing the intervals to 7 days. Could you please check out my new question though?
https://superuser.com/questions/1225283/hiding-rows-in-excel-if-they-are-led-by-an-na-value